# Is this formula for the Hubble expansion rate always correct?

Tags: particle-physics, space-expansion, cosmological-constant

When reading [Sterile Neutrinos as Dark Matter](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9303287) it is stated (on page 5) that the formula for the Hubble expansion rate is

$$H= \frac{1.66 g_*^{1/2} T^2}{m_p}$$

where

- $g_*=10.8$
- $T$ represents the temperature of the universe
- $m_p$ is Planck's mass.

I am trying to solve an equation [How do I integrate and apply limits to this function to obtain the given plot?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776941/how-do-i-integrate-and-apply-limits-to-this-function-to-obtain-the-given-plot)  and was wondering if this formula is a permanent one or if there is a more suitable equation for $H$ that can help me solve the equation.

---

I know that $H=\frac{\dot{a}}{a}$ but I don't think this form can help me.